# GraphQL client times out

Tags: python, graphql

I am using the [gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) GraphQl client in Python to do some querying.
Here is my code:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport

_transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(
    url='<grapql endpoint>',
    use_json=True,
)

client = Client(
    transport=_transport,
    fetch_schema_from_transport=True,
)

query = gql("""
<JSON query>
""")
```

This code gets timed out when fetching the schema from the endpoint.
Have you faced this time-out problem? If so, how did you solve it?
Appreciate your response.
Thank you,
Anjan